# The value of the local variable is not used

Tags: java, eclipse, warnings

I have the following code and I am getting an annoying warning

> The value of the local variable bytesRead is not used

it is bugging me... some say ignore it... but I would rather understand it than blindly ignoring it.

1) Why am I getting this warning.

2) How can I rewrite the following code so it does not throw the warning?

```
        byte[] buffer = new byte[parameters.getSizeOfPacket() + DATA_PACKET_OVERHEAD_LENGTH];
        int bytesRead = -1;
        //System.out.println("Ready to Read");
        while( (bytesRead = in.read( buffer )) != -1 ) {
              .... }
```

Thanks in advance.

Eclipse IDE for Java Developers

Version: Neon.2 Release (4.6.2)

Build id: 20161208-0600

Comment: Well, the warning is self descriptive. You will continue to get the message untils you use that variable inside your code. So far you have only declared it, and assigned a value to it

Comment: Just you don't use buffer, Because of that compiler does't see any meaning of that variable, and It is a memory safe practice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be using the local variable, when you use `buffer` in the loop body. Because, you can only *safely* use `bytesRead` bytes in the `buffer` (typically not everything will end on a nice *buffer boundary*).

Comment: something like this?

Comment: DataPacket dataPacket = null;

Comment: if(bytesRead == parameters.getSizeOfPacket() + DATA_PACKET_OVERHEAD_LENGTH){

Comment: dataPacket = new DataPacket(buffer); }

Comment: Perhaps, if you have a fixed size payload. Other idioms involve only using `bytesRead` bytes from the `buffer` to construct your *local representation*. (`new DataPacket(buffer, bytesRead);` *or* `new DataPacket(Arrays.copyOf(buffer, bytesRead));`).

Comment: Thanks for your help @Elliott Frisch

Comment: I thought the Boolean comparison in the if statement was "using" the variable, but I guess eclipse does not see it that way.